# unable separate source from music using spleeter python library

Tags: python, audio, spleeter, source-separation

I am using `spleeter` python library to separate source from .mp3 audio files. I can separate source when using only one file but when I try to iterate through a number audio files using for loop it doesn't work. I am putting my code and error screenshot for you to look at.

```
from IPython.display import Audio
import spleeter

for item in path:
  !spleeter separate -o output/ {item}
```

This is code for separating source for single audio file

```
!spleeter separate -o output/ audio_example.mp3
```

I am using google `Colab`.
error screenshot:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTfMp.png)

Comment: Can you paste all the errors rather than show the screenshot? The screenshot cuts off the full message. Can you also show the full code you're using? You have code like `for item in path` but what is `path`?

Comment: This is the error message that I get:

Error: Invalid value for 'FILES...': File 'RagaDataset/Hindustani/audio/e771a74d-545d-41d5-816b-43403a818b0c/Kishori_Amonkar/Live_in_Concert:_Nehru_Center_Bombay/Raga_Bhoop_Vilambit_Teentaal_a3479fbe-fea4-4db7-9c1f-8b4ca613e5f0' does not exist.
Usage: `spleeter` separate [OPTIONS] FILES...
Try `spleeter` separate --help' for help.

Comment: It can't find the files, do they exist in the directory?

Comment: Path is list of paths to audio files for which I want to separate source.

This is the code:

```
import spleeter
import json
with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/RagaDataset/Hindustani/_info_/path_mbid_ragaid.json','r') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
path = []
for i in data:
    for j in data[i]:

      if j=='path':
        path.append(data[i][j])
        
ragaid =[]      
for i in data:
    for j in data[i]:

      if j=='ragaid':
        ragaid.append(data[i][j])


for item in path:
  !spleeter separate -o output/ {item}
```

Comment: Yes they do exist in directory

Comment: This is help command given in documents:

``` !spleeter separate --help ```